# Does the appearance of turbidity upon addition of water to an organic solvent mixture imply the presence of nonvolatiles?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I was attempting to ascertain the suitability of GCMS to analyze a solvent mixture recovered from a solgel process. The filtered mixture contains heptane and denatured ethanol as major components and small amounts of HMDS and other impurities (various hydrocarbons in the heptane plus methanol in the ethanol). I spiked the mixture with deionized water and biphasicity ensued. The upper organic layer was clear but the lower aqueous layer was very white and turbid. Does this imply the presence of nonvolatile organics that precipitated, making the mixture unsuitable for GCMS analysis?